# Which sci fi movie quotes this Carl Sagan saying?

Tags: story-identification

Which movie quotes this Carl Sagan saying?
"Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence"

Comment: Lots of them, I expect

Comment: I was pretty sure that quote was from James "The Amazing" Randi.  Perhaps he was quoting Sagan...

Comment: It's pre-Sagan, but he made it famous.

Comment: *Contact* perhaps.

Comment: This goes back at least to Arthur C. Clarke in print.

Comment: Some context would be helpful. Not sure that even relates to sci-fi movies, unless I've missed something...

Comment: not Contact verbatim - though the sentiment is baked in there

Answer (score 1):

According to IMDB, the horror film [Mama](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2023587) quotes that, at least, pretty close. The character Dr. Dreyfuss says

> There is no rational explanation that supports this theory. But it is
>   only the ability to embrace the different reality, that makes science
>   expand beyond the limits of what we know. However, extraordinary
>   claims require extraordinary proofs.